# Meigee Widget code 1.9.1.2 not displaying correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets

I noticed after installing the new security patch my homepage products blocks disappeared. I removed this code which pulled the New products to the home page, however this code blocks all other codes and when I try adding a new widget the size of the blocks are too small

{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_products="all_products" show_paginator="0" products_per_page="6" products_count="6" column_count="6" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}

[image: How it displays]
[image: How it should be]